# How to compress photo taken by Camera.takepicture

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, compression, jpeg

I'm developing an app where the user has the ability to take a picture through my CameraActivity (SurfaceView+Camera) and save it. After that the bitmap will be processed.

Said that let me walk you through details.
The picture is taken with:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {...}
```

I'm not specifying .jpeg quality.
Testing with HTC One S, the picture is taken and then saved. The picture size never exceeds 100kb
Testing with Samsung GT-I9000, the picture is taken and then saved but the difference here is the size, it exceeds 1,2Mb.

Since I'll need to process the bitmap latter on I'm having some **OutOfMemory** issues with the GT-I9000 when I try to decode the bimap to process it:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
    Bitmap savedPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

I've tried to change `Camera Parameters .setJpegQuality(quality)` but I it didn't made a huge difference.

The image will occupy all the screen size and I used this approach [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
It worked, I got rid of **OutOfMemory Exceptions** but still I've some questions:

1. File size differences between devices? I assume HTC One S is better than GT-I9000 so why doesn't save bigger pictures?
2. Image resolution, HTC One S 640x480, GT-I9000 2560x1920 why? Well this answer the first question, but why is this happening?

Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not with the image compression, but with resolution, i.e. size. Different Android devices have different default Picture sizes. But luckily, you have the
[Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize(int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29)
method. You can set the size any time before you call Camera.takePicture() like this:

```
Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
param.setPictureSize(640, 480);
mCamera.setParameters(param);
```

Note that different Android devices support different picture sizes, too. I.e. you cannot set an arbitrary size, you must choose one from the list specific to the device. There is a method Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes().

Note that the supported picture sizes on the same device are different for the two cameras (if the device has front facing camera and rear facing camera). Open the correct camera before you start the queries and sets.

Finally, I should confess that all devices I ever heard about, all supported 640x480 picture size.

Comment: how about using CameraHelper?

Comment: @yozawiratama: what did you ask exactly?

Comment: @AlexCohn sorry if i ask in other people question, but i think this have some relation. i have a program to take picture too, but not using Camera, i use CameraHelper. what i want to ask is, how to set picturesize in my condition use CameraHelper

Comment: @yozawiratama: you will probably get more response if you open a new topic, and describe exactly what you need. Anyway, it's the first time I hear the name **CameraHelper**, therefore my ability to help you is kindof limited.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks alex, finally i try to use your solution :D , thanks for your solution

Comment: param.setPictureSize(640, 480); its working for me if i am giving param.setPictureSize(480, 360); it not working.. can u tell me why??

Comment: @MycareerId: your camera does not support 480x360. You can check the list returned by [params.getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()), or you can search for your device in the database at http://androidfragmentation.com

Comment: thnaks i got another solution but i ll try ur solution too.